# Solve for $k$, $\int_{0}^{k} \frac{dx}{2+8x^{2}} = \frac{\pi}{16}$

Tags: integration

Find the value of k :

$\int_{0}^{k} \frac{dx}{2+8x^{2}} = \frac{\pi}{16}$

My approach:

I substituted $8x = t$

$\therefore$ Integral changes to $\frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{8k} \frac{dt}{2+t^{2}} = \frac{\pi}{16}$ which solves to $tan^{-1} \frac{8k}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$. How do I proceed next for the value of $k$ ?

Comment: I differentiate with respect to k and got: (1/(2+8k^2))=0

Comment: You haven't substituted x correctly in the integrand. Arithmetic mistake there.

Comment: @SatD ooh, silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^k\dfrac{dx}{(1/2)^2+x^2}=\dfrac\pi2$$

$$\iff2\arctan(2x)\big|_0^k=\dfrac\pi2$$

$$\iff2\arctan(2k)=\dfrac\pi2\implies2k=\tan\dfrac\pi4$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{k} \frac{d x}{2+8 x^{2}} &=\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{k} \frac{d(2 x)}{1+(2 x)^{2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left[\tan ^{-1}(2 x)\right]_{0}^{k} \\
&=\frac{1}{4} \tan ^{-1}(2 k) \\
\frac{1}{4} \tan ^{-1}(2 k) &=\frac{\pi}{16} \\
\tan ^{-1}(2 k) &=\frac{\pi}{4} \\
2 k &=1 \\
k &=\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$