# Evaluate $\int_0^k \frac{\cos x}{1+\sin^{2}x}{}x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ for the value of $k$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\int_0^k \frac{\cos x}{1+\sin^{2}x}{}x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ for the value of $k$.

My approach :

Let $1+\sin^{2}x = t \implies dx = \frac{dt}{2 \sin x \cos x}$

and the integral changes to   $\frac{1}{2}\int_1^{1+sin^{2}k} \frac{1}{t \sqrt{t-1}}dt$

Now if I put $t = sec^{2} \theta \implies dt = 2 \sec^{2} \theta \tan\theta d\theta$ which leaves us with $\int \frac{1}{tan \theta} d\theta$ Solving this I get $-cosec^{2} \theta$

Is it correct ? By the end I am confused with the values of limits of integral. How do I calculate $k$ ? Also, is there any oter shorter way of solving this ?

Comment: HINT: The integrand function is the derivative of $$\arctan ( \sin x)$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712655/solve-for-k-int-0k-fracdx28x2-frac-pi16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^k \frac{\cos(x)\ \text{d}x}{1 + \sin^2(x)}$$

Substitute

$$y = \sin(x) ~~~~~~~ \text{d}y = \cos(x)\ \text{d}x$$

Extrema will rum from $\sin(0) = 0$ to $\sin(k)$

$$\int_{0}^{\sin(k)} \frac{\text{d}y}{1 + y^2} = \arctan(y)\bigg|_0^{\sin(k)}$$

So in the end you have to solve this:

$$\arctan(\sin(k)) - \arctan(0) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

That is

$$\arctan(\sin(k)) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$\sin(k) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Which happens for $\sin(k) = 1$ namely

$$k = \frac{\pi}{2}\left(1 + 4n\right) ~~~~~~~~~~~ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

The integrand function is the derivative of $$\arctan ( \sin x)$$
so that you have to solve
$$\arctan (\sin k ) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\sin k = 1$$
$$k = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2m \pi\ \ \ \ , m \in  \Bbb{Z}$$